# The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM,Negotiate'. in windows store apps

Tags: windows-store-apps, ntlm

I have developed an Windows Store App consumes WCF service deployed in another server(not mine) everything works fine until i have disabled the Anonymous Authentication to off getting an error message

```
"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
        The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM,Negotiate'."
```

I have googled and found some of the solutions applied but none of the solutions worked for me.The same WCF service accessing in another project it works fine no complains but when i'm using with windows 8 store apps i'm getting the above error.

Any Solution or Explanation is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hi Dinesh Haraveer,

Please try using Enterprise authentication.

Windows domain credentials enable a user to log into remote resources using their credentials, and act as if a user provided their user name and password. The enterprise Authentication capability is typically used in line-of-business apps that connect to servers within an enterprise. 
You don't need this capability for generic communication across the internet.

Please try looking into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx